# unexpected token illegal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-plus-one

i am trying to run this script but there is an error?

html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
        { parsetags: 'explicit' }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
    gapi.plusone.go();
});

function plusone_vote(obj){
    if(obj.state=="on"){
        alert("Clicked!");
    }
}​

    </script>
    ​
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" callback="plusone_vote">
        </div>
        ​
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the error give you a line number?  A tool like Firebug for Firefox or the Developer Tools in IE8 (press F12) will give you this information :)

Comment: your code is giving some output http://jsfiddle.net/KWkhT/

Comment: Do you get this error in all browsers ? or just chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

Quote `parsetags`, using double quotes:

```
{ "parsetags": "explicit" }
```